# How to magnify a pure CSS menu item when hovering using JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a pure CSS menu and would like to provide a little visual feedback. As the cursor passes over an item, I would like it to magnify to 110% or 120% of its normal size.

I just use text in an unordered list, no images.

Can this be done easily?

---

Update: MS IE 7+  (any thing else is a bonus & probably free anyway)

Comment: Which browsers does this need to work in?

Comment: Would be great also to have a http://jsfiddle.net/ to review...

Comment: How general does this need to be? Could you not create a normal class and a hover class and calculate the magnification yourself?

Comment: 30.  MS IE 7+  (any thing else is a bonus & probably free anyway)  +1 Thanks

Comment: @jswolf19 .. erm, you lost me at "how" ...  (+1)

Comment: @Mawg, sorry ^^ Looks like you got your answer, anyway.

Comment: @Mawg: I don't get a comment notification if you use `30.` :( You'll have to stick to `@thirtydot` :) *(I'm only writing this comment because I happened to look back at this question)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need JavaScript for this. CSS has the `transform` property to apply affine transforms to elements. Just do something like `li:hover { transform: scale(1.2); }`.

It works in all recent version of Safari and Firefox, and IE 9 and newer — and if you're open to JavaScript solutions, [Transformie](http://www.transformie.com/) adds support for 6+.

I made a [Fiddle to illustrate](http://jsfiddle.net/paintitpurple/yfshb/) (includes all the browser prefix versions, but I didn't actually test it in all the browsers, so I might have bungled something somewhere).

Comment: add `zoom : 120%` to that for IE<9

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to just adjust the font-size on hover:

```
li:hover {
    font-size : 1.2em;
}
```

if you've defined everything in `em`s, the entire thing will adjust.  If you have static margins/etc you want to scale, you're still better off just re-defining those in CSS, but you can also use the `zoom` or `transform` properties as Chuck pointed out.